# NHibernate Detecting SSL

Tags: nhibernate, ssl

I'm testing support for encrypted connections from my client application to my SQL server using SSL. I've setup my test certificate and added "encrypt=true" to my connection string and everything is working fine.

If I connect to my SQL server using Management Studio I can view the connection properties and verify that yes, the connection is encrypted.

What I'm trying to figure out is where might a similar property be in NHibernate so that my application can detect that yes, the connection it's using is encrypted?

I've looked through an instance of an ISession object for any property that might indicate an encrypted connection but didn't find anything.